# JQuery autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var availableTutorials = [
   "ActionScript",
   "Boostrap",
   "C",
   "C++",
 ];
 $("#subject_tutorial").autocomplete({
 source: availableTutorials
 });
});
```

Inspecting the element gives:

```
<input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" id="subject_tutorial" name="subject[tutorial]" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

If I try to type something in the text field, nothing happens(no autocomplete list). What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you please be a little more clear on your question?

Comment: Did you remember to include jQuery UI? What errors do you get?

Comment: Did you include the jQuery UI CSS?  Sometimes it's 'working', but isn't easily seen without the appropriate css.

Comment: Yes, I checked that. I printed the version (1.11.2)

Comment: check your form element, did you mark autocomplete="off" ?

Comment: It may have something to do with the css, i'll check that.

Comment: No, I did not mark autocomplete "off"

Comment: Works in isolation... http://jsfiddle.net/an9yeg81/ what did you do differently?

Comment: Try by erasing the last comma (",") at the last element of the array: `"C++",`

Answer (score -1):

Your example works for me, maybe you just forgot to require the jquery ui?

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/to6etrsg/">jsfiddle</a>
```